# I need help building a regular expression that will only leave behind letters and whitespace

Tags: php, regex, replace, special-characters, string-formatting

I am building a form in PHP that requires that the field values only contain letters and whitespace(s).

There are a few small twists on this problem though:

- I can't have more than one whitespace in a row
- There can't be a leading or trailing whitespace in the string (The same effect of the `TRIM()` function)
- The special characters and/or whitespaces that are non-conforming need to be replaced with a single whitespace

**Examples of input & output:**

**INPUT**
`ConQueso, Cheese`
**OUTPUT**
`ConQueso Cheese`
**INPUT**
`0  Eddie Murphy-Washington,   the 3rd  .`
**OUTPUT**
`Eddie Murphy Washington the rd`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply replace `[^a-z]+` with space. And at the end, do a `trim()`.

```
$text = trim(preg_replace('/[^a-z]+/i', ' ', $text));
```

Comment: (Corrected) The only thing this doesn't do is replace instances of multiple spaces within the string: `Murphy-Washington,   the 3rd` to `Murphy Washington the 3rd`

Comment: @aliteralmind it does. Probably you didn't run the code. Just guessed, right? `[^a-z]` anything but letters :-)

Comment: HA!! A space is `[^a-z]` isn't it?  :)  Well now I just *have* to upvote.

Comment: thanks.... that did it.  i used "   h 85  k,en p..ari-s   " (without the quotes) and it returned "h k en p ari s" (again, without the quotes).  i wish i had a intuitive understanding or at least a better grasp on regular expressions.  thanks again

Comment: i ran the code and multiple white spaces are dealt with just the way i needed them to be as i described above... thanks @Sabuj

Comment: @aliteralmind of course. `[^a-z]` = everything but `a` to `z`. So space falls into that.

Answer (score 1):

Because it seems that you want to build a form for personal data input, you should use `[^\pL]` instead of `[^A-Za-z]`, because there can be non ASCII letters (like ä or É) in names. (Additionally to the trim function, as descripted so far.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$text = "Some text here.";
$str = trim(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z\']/', ' ', $text));
```